# Woocommerce API Assign Specific Json Data to Variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, woocommerce

Connected to Woocommerce API and Retrieving all Products

```
getAllProducts = wcapi.get('products')
products = getAllProducts.json()
```

This code returns 3 Products in json format

```
for product in products:
print(['id'])
```

Attempting to retrieve each product id from the json Data but when the code runs it prints

```
['id']
['id']
['id']
```

The number of IDS is correct as i have 3 products in my store. How can i return each product ID and store them into a variable for later use. Below is a snipped of the json data.

```
[{'id': 944, 'name': 'my product 1'}]
```